# Rewrite URL's with variable query string placement with .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to rewrite a few different URL's so they redirect to different places, however they aren't static URL's.

I need to redirect:

```
/index.php?app=core&section=register
```

to for example:

```
htttp://www.mysite.com/register.php
```

However, what I want to do is just make sure that `/index.php?app=core&section=register` *starts with* `/index.php?` but there may be more parameters included and also want to make sure it's still redirected if they are in a different position, so basically it just needs to match it *if* `app=core` *and* `section=register` exists in the URL.

Lastly, if I wanted to add a second one such as..

`/index.php?app=core&section=login` to `htttp://www.mysite.com/login.php` how would I add a second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)app=core(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)section=(register|login)(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%1.php? [NC,L,R=302]
```

As per comments:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)app=core(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)section=(somepath)(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /mypath.php? [NC,L,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure where that redirects it to register.php? ..and the value of section will depend where it gets redirected.

Comment: I have retested this code and `http://localhost/index.php?app=core&section=register` got redirected to `http://localhost/register.php` Make sure this is your very first rule.

Comment: could you tell me how it works so I can add other ones? How would i go about adding another one per my example above.

Comment: You don't to another rule for `/index.php?app=core&section=login` it will be redirected to `/login/php`. 2nd `RewriteCond` in my answer which grabs `section` parameter's value in `%1` variable and reuses that `%1` in target URI of `RewriteRule` as `/%1.php?`

Comment: Oh ok...... well I don't want to redirect ALL URL's like this. Just a few, that's why I wanted specific control on what went where - anything that I don't redirect should just go to it's normal place.

Comment: See updated answer. Now in the regex `(register|login)` you can add more strings as you need.

Comment: Awesome - my only other quesion now is, what if the page it's supposed to be redirected to isn't named the same name as the matching section?

Comment: In that can you will need separate rule sine using `%1` won't help. I will provide an example in answer.

Comment: Ok, so I just use several of those from the second example then? Also, do I need the question mark at the end of `mypath.php` ?

Comment: 1.Yes and 2. `question mark at the end` is needed to strip any existing query string in original URL.